# How to display a number/integer in a TableView?

Tags: uitableview, swift, ios8

I'm trying to build a simple app in which the user would input a date from a date picker(a birthday or any event), then the code would subtract today's date from the date the user gave the app, to get the difference in days and then display a countdown of the number of days left in a table view, along with the name of the event. I have 2 View Controllers, the main TableViewController and then the AddViewController. I've figured out how to get the difference in days, my table view is set up and all the code is running quite well. I just have a problem in displaying the number of days left in the table view as they are integers. I would love to get some help from more experienced developers as I'm relatively new to iOS programming. So without further due, here's my code:

```
@IBAction func addButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    var chosen: NSDate = self.datePicker.date
    var today: NSDate = NSDate()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calendar.components(.DayCalendarUnit, fromDate: today, toDate: chosen, options: nil)
    let secondsInADay = ((60 * 60) * 24)
    let daysLeft = (components.hashValue / secondsInADay)

    var userDefaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults()
    var itemList: NSMutableArray? = userDefaults.objectForKey("itemList") as? NSMutableArray

    var dataSet: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
    dataset.setObject(eventTextField.text, forKey: "itemEventName")
    dataSet.setObject(datePicker.date, forKey: "itemEventDate")
    dataSet.setObject(daysLeft, forKey: "itemDaysLeft")

    if ((itemList) != nil) { 

        var newMutableList: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray() 

        for dict: AnyObject in itemList! {

            newMutableList.addObject(dict as NSDictionary)

        }

        userDefaults.removeObjectForKey("itemList") 
        newMutableList.addObject(dataSet)
        userDefaults.setObject(newMutableList, forKey: "itemList")

    } else {
        userDefaults.removeObjectForKey("itemList")
        itemList = NSMutableArray()
        itemList!.addObject(dataSet)
        userDefaults.setObject(itemList, forKey: "itemList")

    }

    userDefaults.synchronize()
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

}
```

So above is the code in my addViewController, users input a name from a text field, and a date from a date picker. Below is a part of the code in my tableViewController. Basically I want the Int daysLeft to be displayed in the cell.

```
    var toDoItems: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    var userDefaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    var itemListFromUserDefaults: NSMutableArray? = userDefaults.objectForKey("itemList") as? NSMutableArray

    if ((itemListFromUserDefaults) != nil) {
        toDoItems = itemListFromUserDefaults!
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:       NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    var toDoItem: NSDictionary = toDoItems.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSDictionary
    cell.textLabel?.text = toDoItem.objectForKey("itemDaysLeft") as? String 

    return cell
}
```

Comment: What is "toDoItems"?  I see itemList, but no declaration of toDoItems.

Comment: Thanks for helping Bek, I edited the post and added my declaration of toDoItems along with the code in the viewDidAppear func. The rest of the code isn't necessary imo as it only declares the number of rows and sections.

Comment: What shows/happens with your code right now?  Is it a blank cell or do you get an exception/crash?

Comment: The app works fine, so I don't get crashes, I only get a blank cell. I'm thinking it has to do with the fact that I'm trying to display an integer, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Put a break point on this line:     `var toDoItem: NSDictionary = toDoItems.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as NSDictionary` to see what toDoItemContains, just to verify that it is actually what you expect it to be.  But I think the below code may help.

Instead of:
`cell.textLabel?.text = toDoItem.objectForKey("itemDaysLeft") as? String`

try:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = NSString(format:"%@", toDoItem.objectForKey("itemDaysLeft")) as String
```

Comment: I've added a breakpoint and there seems to be an item in memory. I'm trying your suggestion to replace that cell text label... for now it displays (null) in the cell when I run the app. I'll try to find something

Comment: But _what_ is in memory and does an item exist for the key you're looking for?

Comment: There actually is something for the key I'm looking for. I've added a println(toDoItems) line and I see that the number of days left is in memory.

Comment: do println(toDoItem.objectForKey("itemDaysLeft")) to confirm the specific, exact piece you're looking for.  Also, try a different string formatter, like %ld, I'm not too familiar with Swift and in Obj-C, we can't put int/float into a dictionary wo converting it to NSNumber...

Comment: I've tried plenty of string formatters, both "%d" and "%u" work to a certain extent, they display numbers, but for some reason it only displays 0 in all cells. I've tried changing the daysLeft constant by giving it different types but nothing works. I'll keep trying to find a solution, if it doesn't work I'll try adding another object to the dataSet variable by casting the Int into a string. This way I'll be able to display it in the table view and still have the Int for daysLeft. Thanks a lot for the help Bek!

Comment: can you post a screenshot of what shows when you inspect toDoItem in the debugger?  I'd like to see the data types inside the dictionary.

Comment: I'd love to, but I don't have enough "reputation" yet... But if I do println(toDoItem) it'll give me this in the console; {
    itemDateDue = "2015-02-28 20:14:06 +0000";
    itemDaysLeft = 71;
} Is this what you meant?